# Authentication for RedisInsight (via Docker)

Tags: docker, redis

We have a scenario to provide on-premise software (SpringBoot, PostgreSQL, RabbitMQ and Redis as Docker containers) to our customers and thought it would be a good idea to also deploy RedisInsight for debugging purposes in the future. Now we found out that RedisInsight does not provide any authentication mechanisms for the users, meaning that once logged in, everybody in the same network and with knowledge of it has the capability to access it. Even worse - RedisInsight discloses the username/password of the connection on its UI (see image attached).

So the temporary solution is to not expose the RedisInsight port via Docker and only activate it on the fly when required. But having real authentication would, of course, be better. So does anybody know if/how this is possible?

[image: RedisInsight]

Answer (score 0):

We provide a "semi-official" docker image for redisinsight v2.

[oblakstudio/redisinsight](https://hub.docker.com/r/oblakstudio/redisinsight)

It runs as a webservice. You can place it in front of nginx with basic auth or traefik. I noticed the lack of any auth mechanism, so I'm half-inclined to place nginx infront and enable basic auth via envvars.